# Get all items selected from a list Sharepoint with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I would like to get the number of selected items in a sharepoint list when the selection of an element from the list.

Here is my code:

```
$("table.ms-listviewtable td.ms-vb-itmcbx.ms-vb-imgFirstCell div.s4-itm-cbx").click(function() {
    var ClientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var int_count_selected = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ClientContext).length;
    console.log(int_count_selected);
});
```

Here are the results with 1 selected item:

> 0

If I manually entered these commands in the console of my browser it works.

I think that my script run before the Sharepoint's script.

How can i do for run my script after sharepoint script ?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change your code to something like this (try to use CountDictionary()):

```
this.clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
this.selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(this.clientContext);
var ci = CountDictionary(selectedItems);
```

I use it when I need to enable/disable ribbons according to selected items number.

If that won't help you can try with:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(yourCountingMethod, "sp.js");
```

It will execute your method after sp.js is ready.

What browser are you using? There are many reports of similar bugs on non IE browsers.

Also make sure your event is executing... ;)

Comment: Same problem with your method. When i check line the count = 0. When i uncheck line the count = 1.

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you mean with "check/uncheck line"?
Sry I can't help you much further, my SP trial expired so I can't test the code.

Comment: I would like to detect the selection of one or more elements of a sharepoint list (documents selected, news selected etc ...) and count the number of selected items.

Picture here:
[link](http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/1769/selectf.jpg)